# PHP / MySQL search to cater for missed hyphens

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a pretty simple search function in PHP (Codeigniter) that takes a query and attempts to match it against a name in a MySQL table. The table splits the name into alias, firstname and lastname:

```
$this->db->where("alias LIKE '%$query%' OR firstname LIKE '%$query%' OR lastname LIKE '%$query%' OR CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) LIKE '%$query%'");
```

This works for most cases. The problem arises with one of the names in the database -- the surname is `Smith-Ponsonby` (for the sake of argument). If the user searches for `Smith-Ponsonby`, the correct result is shown. But if the user accidentally misses out the hyphen and searches for `Smith Ponsonby`, nothing is returned (as is expected with my code). But I want to cater for these accidental cases. I need something quite simple, but my searches have only found quite elaborate fuzzy search algorithms. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like `'%query%' like REPLACE(lastname, '-', '')`?  That is, simply use a string function to remove the `-` if it exists, then compare?

Comment: No, but I have now, and it works beautifully. Thanks. If you want to make it an answer I'll mark it as right.

Comment: Try to replace all unwanted symbols in your `query` like space, hyphen, colon, etc. to `_` that means only one any symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a fulltext index to your text fields, for example:

```
create table people (
    id int unsigned auto_increment not null primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    fulltext(name)
);
```

Insert some test values:

```
insert into people (name) values ('smith'),('smithers'),('wosmithling'),('smith-ponsonby');
```

Then query with the `MATCH()` operator, for example, just for 'smith':

```
select * from people where match(name) against ('smith' in boolean mode);
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | smith          |
|  4 | smith-ponsonby |
+----+----------------+
```

With a dash:

```
select * from people where match (name) against ('smith-ponsonby' in boolean mode);
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | smith          |
|  4 | smith-ponsonby |
+----+----------------+
```

With a space:

```
select * from people where match (name) against ('smith ponsonby' in boolean mode);
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | smith          |
|  4 | smith-ponsonby |
+----+----------------+
```